# What is the definition of: Vanish to infinite order at the boundary?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Hy all

I am reading a paper about PDE and i got a compact manifold $\mathbb B$ and they or the paper had defined $C^{\infty,\infty}(\mathbb B)$ as all functions smooth in the interior of $\mathbb B$ and vanish to infinite order at the boundary, i tried to researh that definition but i don not where to finding this, somebody can help me please or give me one referent book. Thank you

Comment: I think it's just all derivative goes to $0$ at the boundary.

Comment: @Paichu, do you mean that when  we are near to the boundary and taking derivates of any order then the value is less than epsilon right? Thank you so much

Comment: I believe so. But I can't be 100% sure unless I read the paper. :(